# Access Lightswitch Dataset Item on screen

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, this, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am working on a Lightswitch HTML application.  I Have a `Browse` screen with a button which opens an `Add` screen.

My `Browse` screen is populated by a `view`which may have multiple records per employee. The `view` is being filtered at the `Datasource` level based on `this.Application.User.Name`. That filter sets it such that only records for the active user show on the `Browse` screen.

> I want to set the default `EmployeeID` on my `Add` screen to be the `EmployeeID` of the active user, which will come from my `view`.

Here is my code for the button:

```
myapp.BrowseTimesheetRecords.AddNewRecord_execute = function (screen) {
    myapp.showAddTimesheetRecord(null, {
        beforeShown: function (addScreen) {
            var newItem = new myapp.TBG_KeepInTimesheet();
            newItem.EmployeeID = screen.TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Detail.EmployeeID;
            newItem.CreateDate = new Date;
            newItem.EffectiveDate = new Date;
            newItem.CreatedBy = this.Application.User.Name;
            addScreen.TBG_KeepInTimesheet = newItem;
        },
        afterClosed: function () {
            screen.TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Details.load();
        }
    });
};
```

I believe the problem is that I have no selected `EmployeeID` so I can't use `screen.`

> Is there a way to select and pass the `Distinct` `EmployeeID` from my `DataSource` within that JavaScript `Execute` function? There will only ever be 1 distinct `EmployeeID` though there may be many records

For reference here is the filter on my dataset:

```
partial void TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Details_Filter(ref Expression<Func<TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Detail, bool>> filter)
{
    filter = e => e.UserLogin == this.Application.User.Name;
}
```

`TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Details` is the name of my `view` within the Application.
`TBG_KeepInTimesheet` is the name of the table which my view draws from.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you set a break point at the line newItem.EmployeeID = screen.TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Detail.EmployeeID;, do you see a collection of obects? If you're guaranteed to return at least one, can you try indexing into the element and retrieving the EmployeeID?

Comment: this can be done however before I post an answer, would you be able to use the username? as this is a lot easier than using there specific ID :) and by username I mean the one generated by the lightswitch application itself

Comment: Hi sorry for my delay, I got pulled away by a few other projects and am only now circling back. To filter the Browse screen, I can use the `username` however for my `AddTimesheetRecord` screen I would like to pass the `EmployeeID` to make reporting easier. I am already passing `This.Application.User.Name` and I have added the corresponding DB field to my datasets but I can't seem to work out the joins. I will post an update when I have gotten my bearings back on this project